# Test multiple port connection via powershell

Tags: powershell

If any of the ports are closed, the script will not continue to run.

If both ports are open, the script will run.

There are 2 functions as below. they return FALSE if the port is closed and TRUE if it is open.

I have tried  something like below.  But its not working. I am assuming , because of `exit 0` inside first function.

```
$areKMSAvailable = tcping -Server 192.168.2.2 -Port 1688

$areRPCAvailable = Test-RPC -ComputerName 192.168.2.2 -Verbose



function ConnectExitKMS {
    Write-Output "Please fix the closed port 1688 before attempting to activate"
    Start-Sleep 10
    exit 0
}

    if ( ! $areKMSAvailable) {
        ConnectExitKMS
    }

function ConnectExitRPC {
    Write-Output "Please fix the closed port 135 before attempting to activate"
    Start-Sleep 10
    exit 0
}

    if ( ! $($areRPCAvailable.EndPointMapperOpen)) {
        ConnectExitRPC
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using exit 0? Nobody can test your script because you're not provding the code used for `tcping` and `Test-RPC`
Powershell has a command that can test for port connections: `Test-NetConnection`

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly room for improvment but, as far I understood your question, this should do the trick.

```
function Test-ports
{   [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (   [string]$hostname,
        [int[]]$ports
    )

    Begin
    {   $allOpen = $false
    }
    Process
    {   foreach ($port in $ports)
        {   if (-not (Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $hostname -Port $port -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).TcpTestSucceeded)
            {   #port closed
                Write-Verbose "$($port) closed"
                Return $allOpen
            }
            else
            {   Write-Verbose "$($port) open"
            }
        }
        $allOpen = $true
    }
    End
    {   Return $allOpen
    }
}

$portsToTest = @(80,443,1688)
$hostname = "XYZ"

if (Test-ports -hostname $hostname -ports $portsToTest -verbose)
{   #do things (or not) as all open
}
else
{   #do things (or not) as at least one closed
}
```

Comment: In your script , if both ports are closed , I am getting an warning like below. So , if clause is working (#do things (or not) as all open part ) . But its wrong. WARNING: TCP connect to (192.168.229.1 : 135) failed
WARNING: Ping to 192.168.229.1 failed with status: TimedOut
VERBOSE: 135 closed
All ports opened

Comment: This is part of possible improvements :  check if host is at least reachable before probing the ports.......